# Different monkey patch scripts for the same method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

Can we use two different monkey patch scripts for the same method which is getting called at different lines inside a python function?

```
# abc.py
def add(a,b):
sum=a+b
return sum


# file1.py
def xyz():
        ...
        sum = add(i,j)
        ...
        ...
        addition = add(v,u)
        ...
        ...

# test_file1.py
def test_xyz():
        ..... # ---> I need to add two different monkey patch scripts for
              # add() with different results within pytest
```

Can anyone help me with monkey patching?

Comment: can you provide more detail? if it is just addition why even patch? please show expected outcome in pseudo code if need be

Answer (score 1):

[Side effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) is meant just for this purpose - it can be used to return different values in the same mock. This example is taken from the documentation - 3 consecutive calls to the mock would produce different results as specified in `side_effect`:

```py
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.side_effect = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> mock(), mock(), mock()
(5, 4, 3)
```

To make it work with your example and [pytest mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) I placed your source files inside `q72959276` module so your `abc.py` doesn't override the [built-in python ABC module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). I also made the xyz method return the mocked values so it's easy to assert things are working:

```
# q72959276/abc.py
def add(a, b):
    sum = a + b
    return sum


# q72959276/file1.py
from .abc import add


def xyz():
    sum = add(1, 2)
    addition = add(3, 4)

    return sum, addition


# tests/test_file1.py
from q72959276.file1 import xyz


def test_xyz(mocker):
    mocker.patch("q72959276.file1.add", side_effect=[20, 42])
    assert 20, 42 == xyz()
```